# Remove unnecessary parts on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

well, i want to make an svg or canvas generator using coordinates(lat,log), searched for another answer to guide me how it would part the process, then i found some answer and a jsfiddle similar to what i was looking for (http: //jsfiddle.net/rfygLwk3/2/), this method is faithful to what I intend to do, but there is an error in it, when making a rectangle it does what it should do but when trying to create another shape it nn works as expected, I try to create an "M" with these coordinates:

```
    {lat: -10.98989614, lng:-60.73250771},
    {lat: -10.94220304, lng:-60.7327652},
    {lat: -10.96461807, lng:-60.70547104},
    {lat: -10.94270866, lng:-60.68555832},
    {lat: -10.98955911, lng:-60.68736076},
    {lat: -10.98989614, lng:-60.73250771},
```

it covers the entire square of the canvas, if anyone can give me a north it will be much appreciated

---- edit 1.2v ---

Well, what I'm trying is to build some function that creates SVG based on lat log coordinates, it would be like this, on my site I can delimit it on a map (as if it were a plantation area): [image] , this map of the maps would be shown elsewhere on the site (this is not a problem), but my boss asked me to create a SVG map based on these bounded area coordinates, being the final SVG form like this:

[image]

Comment: You need to put the `ctxt.beginPath();
  ctxt.moveTo(0, 0);` outside the loop before the loop begins. You also need to put the `ctxt.closePath();
  ctxt.fill();` outside the loop after the loop ends

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you very much, i've been stuck on this bug for days.

Comment: I found it easier to create a clip-path on a div than draw on a canvas, Is that acceptable?

Comment: Would a svg image be a good candidate for this? I mean, why to struggle with canvas if you can do it with a svg? Or, maybe if you explain better what you want to achieve then I could probably help you in a better way.

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS This idea is very good, but I don't really know how SVG works, my plan is to create maps based on coordinates (a lat log array list) that is similar to what I have in google maps api maps, these svgs would be like a withdrawal from google maps that could be used in other places without having to make more requests on the google maps api, if you can help me, i would be eternally grateful.

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS later I wanted to put some lines representing plant rows

Comment: Damião França, I know svg very well but do not know a thing about what you are trying to build, that's why, in order to help you, I must understand what you want first.

Comment: @A Haworth no, because this process is to create maps, this would be a faithful example: one I have a plantation, so I go to my website and delimit it in google maps api, now I get the coordinates of the plantation and try to create a SVG faithful to google's maps created

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS OK, I added some information about the project.

Comment: Then what you need is to generate a svg image just like the last image you show, or mixing the map and the limited area?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS Yes, I need to generate an image exactly as I showed, but this code will be used to generate several svgs (several plantation boundaries as I showed), got it? will be a reusable code

Comment: There are several js libraries to dinamically generate svg files but I have never used them and even know their names, I think Rafael is one of them. I use Inkscape to draw my svgs as i am mostly a graphic designer. Try to look out there using a search engine like Google search or the one of your preference.

Comment: I think this is use to create maps https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj16b6thZ3yAhUJRDABHS5pDpoQFnoECAoQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F37257826%2Fhow-to-save-automatically-a-html-svg-element-generated-dynamically%2F37258379&usg=AOvVaw15kxVjD86NGtEydrERGZ52 and also this one to generate svg https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj16b6thZ3yAhUJRDABHS5pDpoQFnoECB0QAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpablojs.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw04cz2un15_KvSY-f-dL-yw

Comment: @SIMBIOSE but there is a problem, there are several SVG generator libraries but they nn create from coordinates(lat log).

Comment: @SIMBIOSE but anyway, thanks for the help.